# How to move up the lable text without moving the hint text in TextFormField (flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

I have the following widget tree: `SizedBox( child: Container ( child: TextFormField(),),),`

I want the labelText to be inline with the container's top edge. `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(x, x, x, x),` and `EdgeInsets.only(x, x, x, x),` hasn't helped at all.

`contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0, ),//paddingin InputDecoration`

`padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0,),//padding Container`

I have Container **1** which is the initial view.

Using the above EdgeInsets I get container **2**. What can I do to achieve Container **3** ?
[image]

**Edit**

````
return SizedBox(
      height: 105,
      child: Container(
        decoration: decorationBox.copyWith(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0,),
        width: 350.0,
        child: Center(
          child: TextFormField(
            cursorColor: color,
            validator: validate,
            obscureText: obscure,
            keyboardType: keyboard,
            onSaved: onSaved,
            
            decoration: decorationText.copyWith(
              hintText: hintText,
              labelText: labelText,
             
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                icon,
                color: color,
                size: 40.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );```
````

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using other widgets in place of SizedBox like UnconstrainedBox, and could you show full code for container to understand the problem more better.

So what I have found is, SizedBox simply creates a box with given width/height and doesn't allow child to go beyond given dimensions.

so you can use limited box instead of SizedBox and set margin/padding to text container so that it can go outside box.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using LimitedBox, it gave me container 3 but it is all cramped up and i don't have any bottom padding. I also tried UnconstrainedBox it gives the same effect as a SizedBox.